# Sequelize ORM add primary key column in selection, While I excluded it

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

> I've prepare a query through sequelize, which get record with
>   association hasOne,  aggregation function SUM() and with Group By
>   clause, But sequelize query automatically added target table primary
>   key column and  that column cause group by clause error.

Here is my Node Function, Which get data from service.

```
exports.getCustomerByManagerId = async (userId, limit, offset) => {
  const customers = await models.Customer.findAndCountAll({
    where: { account_manager_id: userId },
    include: [
      { model: models.UserProfile, as: 'accountmanager', attributes: userProfileSanitizer.sanitizeuserProfile() },
      {
        model: models.Task,
        as: 'customertask',
        attributes: [
          [sequelize.literal('SUM(IF(customertask.status = 1, 1, 0))'), 'todo'],
          [sequelize.literal('SUM(IF(customertask.status = 2, 1, 0))'), 'pendingTask'],
          [sequelize.literal('SUM(IF(customertask.status = 3, 1, 0))'), 'completeTask'],
          [sequelize.literal('COUNT(customertask.id)'), 'totalTask']
        ]
      }
    ],
    group: ['`customer`.`customer_id`'],
    order: [
      ['createdAt', 'DESC']
    ],
    limit,
    offset
  });
```

And sequelize query produce result query AS :

```
SELECT `customer`.`customer_id`, `customer`.`userId`, `customer`.`name`, `customer`.`account_manager_id`, `customer`.`start_date`, `customer`.`renewal_date`, `customer`.`customer_type`, 
`customer`.`SKU`, `customer`.`variation`, `customer`.`similar`, `customer`.`setCost`, `customer`.`SKUCost`, `customer`.`variationCost`, `customer`.`similarCost`, 
`customer`.`actual_monthly_cost`, `customer`.`address1`, `customer`.`address2`, `customer`.`city`, `customer`.`state`, `customer`.`category`, `customer`.`createdAt`, 
`customer`.`updatedAt`, `accountmanager`.`userId` AS `accountmanager.userId`, `accountmanager`.`firstName` AS `accountmanager.firstName`, `accountmanager`.`lastName` 
AS `accountmanager.lastName`, `accountmanager`.`isTermsofService` AS `accountmanager.isTermsofService`, 
`customertask`.`id` AS `customertask.id`,
SUM(IF(customertask.status = 1, 1, 0)) AS `customertask.todo`, 
SUM(IF(customertask.status = 2, 1, 0)) AS `customertask.pendingTask`, 
SUM(IF(customertask.status = 3, 1, 0)) AS `customertask.completeTask`, 
COUNT(customertask.customer_id) AS `customertask.totalTask` 
FROM `customer` AS `customer` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_profiles` AS `accountmanager` ON `customer`.`account_manager_id` = `accountmanager`.`userId` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `task` AS `customertask` ON `customer`.`customer_id` = `customertask`.`customer_id` 
WHERE `customer`.`account_manager_id` = 1 
GROUP BY `customer`.`customer_id`
ORDER BY `customer`.`createdAt` DESC LIMIT 0, 10;
```

> This is added by sequelize which cause error `customertask`.`id` AS
>   `customertask.id`,  and when I remove this line and execute query in
>   mysql workbench editor then it works
>
> ERROR AS : Error Code: 1055. Expression #27 of SELECT list is not in
>   GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'DBName.customertask.id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 6):

Adding raw:true will help and it will not add the primary key by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this by saying that I don't know if this is the solution of not but it's too much to write in a comment..

Have you tried explicitly excluding the `id` field from `customertask` so it's not a selected attribute? e.g.

```
exports.getCustomerByManagerId = async (userId, limit, offset) =>
{
    const customers = await models.Customer.findAndCountAll({
        where: { account_manager_id: userId },
        include: [
            { model: models.UserProfile, as: 'accountmanager', attributes: userProfileSanitizer.sanitizeuserProfile() },
            {
                model: models.Task,
                as: 'customertask',
                attributes: {
                    include: [
                        [ sequelize.literal('SUM(IF(customertask.status = 1, 1, 0))'), 'todo' ],
                        [ sequelize.literal('SUM(IF(customertask.status = 2, 1, 0))'), 'pendingTask' ],
                        [ sequelize.literal('SUM(IF(customertask.status = 3, 1, 0))'), 'completeTask' ],
                        [ sequelize.literal('COUNT(customertask.id)'), 'totalTask' ]
                    ],
                    exclude: [ 'id' ] // <---------- exclude the id
                }
            }
        ],
        group: [ '`customer`.`customer_id`' ],
        order: [
            [ 'createdAt', 'DESC' ]
        ],
        limit,
        offset
    });
};
```

Comment: Let me try this